# MySQL: Can I create a database with command `cp` on centos?

Tags: mysql, linux

Creating a database with mysql command is like this:

```
create database new_york;
use new_york;
create table authors(id int,name varchar(10),gender varchar(5));
create table articles(id int,title varchar(255),content text);
```

Above I created a database named `new_york`, and it has two tables `authors` and `articles`.

[image]

Now I need another database named `los_angeles`,it has the same tables as `new_york`,and each table has the same structure.
I can repeat the sentences above to create it.

```
create database los_angeles;
use los_angeles;
create table authors(id int,name varchar(10),gender varchar(5));
create table articles(id int,title varchar(255),content text);
```

But can I create it using command `cp` of linux? like this:

```
cd /var/lib/mysql
cp -a new_york los_angeles
```

Now in `/var/lib/mysql`,there is the folder `los_angeles`,and there are table files in this folder.

So is that ok to create databases with  command `cp` if they have the same tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not create any database using cp command. the easiest way to do that is

1- dump new_york database without data.

```
mysqldump -u${USERNAME} -p --no-data new_york > new_york.sql
```

2- create los_angeles, and import new_york database dump.

```
CREATE DATABASE los_angeles;
use los_angeles;
source  new_york.sql;
```

Hope This helps